# (Python Scipy) How to flatten a csr_matrix and append it to another csr_matrix?

Tags: python, xml, nlp, scipy, classification

I am representing each XML document as a feature matrix in a csr_matrix format. Now that I have around 3000 XML documents, I got a list of csr_matrices. I want to flatten each of these matrices to become feature vectors, then I want to combine all of these feature vectors to form one csr_matrix representing all the XML documents as one, where each row is a document and each column is a feature.

One way to achieve this is through this code

```
X= csr_matrix([a.toarray().ravel().tolist() for a in ls])
```

where ls is the list of csr_matrices, however, this is highly inefficient, as with 3000 documents, this simply crashes!

In other words, my question is, how to flatten each csr_matrix in that list 'ls' without having to turn it into an array, and how to append the flattened csr_matrices into another csr_matrix.

Please note that I am using python with Scipy

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you use `csr_matrix` for each XML, maybe it's better to use `lil`, `lil_matrix` support reshape method, here is an example:

```
N, M, K = 100, 200, 300
matrixs = [sparse.rand(N, M, format="csr") for i in xrange(K)]
matrixs2 = [m.tolil().reshape((1, N*M)) for m in matrixs]
m1 = sparse.vstack(matrixs2).tocsr()

# test with dense array
#m2 = np.vstack([m.toarray().reshape(-1) for m in matrixs])
#np.allclose(m1.toarray(), m2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a robust way to deal with this. I also found the reason for the crashing, as the main bottleneck was the .tolist(). Lists in python are incredibly slow, compared to scipy matrices which have an underlying C implementation