# how to use vstack in a for loop in order to append csr_matrix matrices together

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using the following piece of code in order to concatenate matrices of type `csr_matrix`  together. It is based on [How to flatten a csr_matrix and append it to another csr_matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563396/python-scipy-how-to-flatten-a-csr-matrix-and-append-it-to-another-csr-matrix)

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re, sys
import os
import numpy

from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse import vstack


if __name__ == "__main__": 

  centroids = []
  for i in range(0,3):
    a = csr_matrix([[i,i,i]])
    centroids = vstack((centroids, a), format='csr')

  print "centroids : " + str(centroids.shape[0]) +"  "+ str(centroids.shape[1])
```

---

As output I am getting

```
centroids : 4  3
```

The size of centroids should be 3 and not 4. Am I concatenating them correctly?

---

I tried the following just to see if I can ignore the first rows:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
matrix = euclidean_distances(centroids[1:][:], centroids[1:][:])
print matrix
[[ 0.          1.73205081  3.46410162]
 [ 1.73205081  0.          1.73205081]
 [ 3.46410162  1.73205081  0.        ]]
```

It sounds ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the concatenation of `[]` with `csr_matrix([[i,i,i]])` that is giving you the problem.

```
centroids = []
a = csr_matrix([[1,2,3]])
centroids = vstack((centroids, a), format='csr')
print centroids.toarray()
```

gives you

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
```

So just start incrementing the counter from `1`

```
centroids = []
for i in range(1,3):
    a = csr_matrix([[i,i,i]])
    centroids = vstack((centroids, a), format='csr')
```

By the way, stacking `csr_matrices` is really inefficient, as the sparsity of `centroids` keeps changing in every iteration. Perhaps, better if you store row, column and coefficients and then call `sparse` on them at once. Have a look [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html).

Comment: will it affect the results? or it's an optimization problem?

Comment: It shouldn't affect your results.

Comment: sorry I am knew to csr_matrix. Thank you for your help. I'll check the the Python documentation for scipy

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `vstack` in a loop, since it's expensive to change the size and sparsity of the matrix in every iteration.
Instead do:

```
centroids = []
for i in range(3):
  a = csr_matrix([[i, i, i]])
  centroids.append(a)
centroids = vstack(centroids, format="csr")
```

Comment: yes @ivanab. It really slowed the execution time. I didn't know that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`vstack` is treating that initial `centroids` values as a 1 row matrix

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse
In [2]: centroids = []
In [3]: a = sparse.csr_matrix([[0,0,0]])
In [4]: b=sparse.vstack((centroids,a),format='csr')
In [5]: b
Out[5]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [6]: b.A
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

`a` is all zeros, so it is a `csr` with 0 stored elements.  To make things more obvious make `a` with nonzero values:

```
In [7]: a = sparse.csr_matrix([[1,1,1]])
In [8]: b=sparse.vstack((centroids,a),format='csr')
In [9]: b
Out[9]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [10]: b.A
Out[10]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

You should have printed `centroids` after the iteration; the nature of the problem would have been a lot more obvious.

What you are doing is like:

```
In [12]: x=[0]
In [13]: for i in range(3): x.append(i)
In [14]: x
Out[14]: [0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Yes, you could use `centroids` by slicing off the 1st row, but that's a clumsy way of solving a more basic problem - the starting value of your iteration.

If I start with a `centroids` with 0 rows I can avoid the problem

```
In [30]: centroids = sparse.csr_matrix((0,3),dtype=int)
In [31]: b=sparse.vstack((centroids,a),format='csr')
In [32]: b
Out[32]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [33]: b.A
Out[33]: array([[1, 1, 1]])
```

If you must do iteration with something like `sparse.vstack`, make sure you start with a meaningful value.

But as others point out, building a sparse array by repeated `vstack` is an inefficient process.

Comment: Now I get it. It is very slow to build it. i didn't really understand what you meant till now. I have to find another way as romeric said. You were right